# Primefaces Calender component not working inside the form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I used Primefaces calender component and it is not working inside the form.When I click On textfield, the popup quickly disappears as soon it shows. 
outside `h:form` popup is showing itself but overall component still not works like month/year not selectable.nay suggestoin why ?

Following is my `advSearch.xhtml` facelet whose template is `Master.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/MasterPage/Master.xhtml">

<ui:define name="Search">

    <h:form id="advSearch" onmousemove="removeExtra()">

            <p:layout style="width:1218px;height:558px;" id="layout">



                <p:layoutUnit position="center" styleClass="resultDiv">

                    <div class="advDiv">

                        <div class="advHeader">Find documents That Have...</div>
                        <div class="advBody">

                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputText styleClass="advLabel" value="Subject"></h:outputText></td>
                                    <td><h:inputText
                                            value="#{advanceSearchController.subject}"
                                            styleClass="txtfield"
                                            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { document.getElementById('advSearch:advButton').click(); return false; }"></h:inputText>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputText styleClass="advLabel" value="Signed By"></h:outputText></td>
                                    <td><h:inputText
                                            value="#{advanceSearchController.signBy}"
                                            styleClass="txtfield"
                                            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { document.getElementById('advSearch:advButton').click(); return false; }"></h:inputText></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputText styleClass="advLabel"
                                            value="Archived From"></h:outputText></td>
                                    <td><p:calendar styleClass="txtfield" mode="popup"
                                            navigator="true" yearRange="1900:2015" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                            converter="CalendarDateStringConverter"
                                            value="#{advanceSearchController.fromdate}" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputText styleClass="advLabel" value="To"></h:outputText></td>
                                    <td><p:calendar styleClass="txtfield" mode="popup"
                                            navigator="true" yearRange="1900:2015" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                            converter="CalendarDateStringConverter"
                                            value="#{advanceSearchController.todate}" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <h:commandButton id="advButton" styleClass="btn"
                                value="Advanced Search"
                                action="#{advanceSearchController.advanceSearch}"
                                style="background-color:#FEAA41;background-image:none;color:white;font-weight:bold;"></h:commandButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </div>

    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the minimal configuration (a form with only the calendar inside) and check if it still doesn't work. Report the results here.

Comment: Code seems fine but one thing,I just see is a JS function that you called on onmousemove="removeExtra()" on your form.As you stated that popup quickly disappeared mean it comes and then disappeared.It shows that calender is working fine but there is wrong somewhere else.check two things (1) does field disappears when you move the cursor after click in the calender field (mean just click and see if it disappears,if no then move the cursor then check because you called your JS function onmouseover event so it might be mouse movement issue)(2) remove this removeExtra() function and then check

Comment: @Matt Handay executed that same form as separate html page with its h:head and h:body (i.e not included in Master.xhtml) .The calender worked fine.

Comment: @despicable about your first point i didnt get exactly what you mean by "field" disappears.The cursor appears on the textfield and on two three click the popup of calender shows up. As soon as i move the mouse cursor down to calender ,that calender disappears.

Comment: @despicable after removing the onmousemove="removeExtra()" from form, the calender works fine

Comment: mean when you stay away the cursor or click somewhere else then calender get removed? Try to remove the `onmousemove="removeExtra()"` from your form and then check

Comment: yes that was my guess that there is some logic in your JS function which is mixing up with this component. Let me post it as a answer please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems fine but one thing,I just see is a JS function that you called on `onmousemove="removeExtra()"` on your form.
As you stated that popup quickly disappeared mean it comes and then disappeared.It shows that calender is working fine but there is wrong somewhere else.
Please check two things 

 **(1)** does field disappears when you move the cursor after click in the calender field (mean just click and see if it disappears,if no then move the cursor then check  because you called your JS function onmouseover event so it might be mouse movement issue) 
 **(2)** remove this removeExtra() function and then check